# Emberjs without ember data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Im following this example [Ember without Ember data](http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html)

And tested to get my Teambox tasks, ( for make this work you need a teambox account and be logged in cause in this example I didnt add authenticacion);

```
http://jsbin.com/aZIXaYo/65/edit
```

If you are loggged in, the tasks appear correctly on the console.log

```
App.RedditLink = Ember.Object.extend({});

App.RedditLink.reopenClass({

  todooo: function(){
    $.ajax({
     url:"https://teambox.com/api/2/tasks",
     type: "GET",
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success:function(json){
        var links = Em.A();
        json.forEach(function (child) {
    links.pushObject(App.RedditLink.create(child));
         //console.log(chilppld.name);
        });
        console.log(links);
        return links;
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     }
    });
  }

});
```

This is what appears on the console

```
[Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, Class, _super: undefined, nextObject: function, firstObject: undefined, lastObject: undefined, contains: function…]
```

But on the template the data dont appears, check [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aZIXaYo/65/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get results from your url, but your `todoo` method doesn't return the array. Your current implementation is returning the array from ajax success callback. This is the updated version:

```
App.RedditLink.reopenClass({

  todooo: function() {    
    var links = Em.A();

    $.ajax({
     url:"https://teambox.com/api/2/tasks",
     type: "GET",
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success:function(json){        
        json.forEach(function (child) {
          links.pushObject(App.RedditLink.create(child));         
        });                
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     }      
    });

    return links;
  }

});
```

I hope it helps